Filter values as argument in functions
How to model a cube and query to filter rows containing a value in array columns using Amazon Athena?
select * 
from my_table
where contains(my_array_column,'foobar')

So I can write a filter like:
{
  "member": "my_array_dimension",
  "operator": "equals",
  "values": ["foobar"]
}

I tried to used FILTER_PARAMS but no luck.

can you share the creation script of your table CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE.... ? the source data is csv,json,.. ?

Data is in parquet format used by delta lake. DDL would look like: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
my_array_column ARRAY, ...

If you can use UNEST you can try some thing like this:
WITH expanded_table AS (
SELECT field1, field2, element
FROM table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(array_column) AS t (element)
)
SELECT *
FROM expanded_table
WHERE element = 'foobar';

Check the usage from AWS Docs, hope this help.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/filtering-arrays.html

Thanks for suggestion. I'm aware of unnest. The problem is that it brings unnecessary complexity to the query. I have many array columns that the user can choose to filter from (zero or many filters). Therefore I would have to unnest all of them in the inner query (many unnecessary cross joins)

I added another answer, I adidn't get formatting the code in comments so here it's below :
I tought it was one array column, so if you are using athen engine version 3 which based on trino, you can try to use :
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE any_match(my_array_column, x -> x = 'foobar') ;

Array functions from : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions.html

It's not clear for me how to write it as a dimension: my_array_dimension: { sql: any_match(my_array_column, x -> x = 'foobar'), type: string } How to get 'foobar' from query?
Cube.js will produce sql: WHERE any_match(my_array_column, x -> x = 'foobar') = ?

Maybe     sql: any_match(${CUBE.myArrayColumn}, x -> x = ${FILTER_PARAMS.myArrayDimension.values[0]}),  type: boolean

Tried: ${FILTER_PARAMS.my_cube.myArrayDimension.values[0]}
Result: TypeCannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
